# How to get more detail than 'Webpack Compilation Error' with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cypress

Whenever there is an error inside one of my imported modules, all I get from Cypress is the message `Error: Webpack Compilation Error`. There doesn't seem to be a useful error stack anywhere so it is incredibly frustrating to have to hunt down the source of the error. I was wondering if there is a way of getting more details on the error?

I'm writing the tests in TypeScript and using [cypress-webpack-preprocessor](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor) to compile the test code.

Here is the `webpack.config.js` that I'm passing to cypress-webpack-preprocessor:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  }
};
```

Here is the screenshot of the lovely error message:

[image]

Comment: Any solution to this? We're running into the same error.

Comment: @tamarabyte I'm afraid not... Maybe open an issue on the [cypress repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress)?

Comment: Also getting this issue...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see your webpack logs by running cypress in debug mode [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Print-DEBUG-logs)

Mac/Linux

```
DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run
```

Windows

```
set DEBUG=cypress:*
cypress run
```

It is quite a bit of output, as there's logging from everything cypress does - one of which is `cypress:webpack`, which can give you the full message.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction! They should really show a user-friendly error message by default but this will suffice for now!

Answer (score 2):

I observed giving an incorrect path could give this error. Try to give a full path as shown below.

Incorrect path

```
import { Login } from 'Login.js';
```

Correct Path

```
import { Login } from '../page-object-model/Login.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { should } = require("chai")
```

Remove the above line from your code. This line maybe on the top of your `commands.js` file.

Answer (score -1):

The error arises when a Cypress function is invoked intentionally or unintentionally within the commands.js file.

For example, by calling the cypress( ) function, Cypress will import a specific line of code in the commands.js file, resulting **Error: Webpack Compilation** error when you execute a Cypress test.

`const cypress = require("cypress");`